# calulating javascript event on keyup

Tags: javascript

the following works in Jfiddle-but when i use it in original form, the total_full and total_half fields are calculated automatically from other fields, and therefore do not have a keyup or keydown event? therefore the "sub_total" field is not calculating when the "total_full" and total_half fields are updated?

HTML

```
<td>Total Cost Full Day</td>
<input type="text" name="total_full" id="total_full"  />

<td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>

 <td>Total Cost Half Day</td>
<input type="text" name="total_half" id="total_half"  />

<td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
//Calculate Sub Total


function calculateSubTotal() {

    var SubTotal = +document.getElementById("total_full").value + +document.getElementById("total_half").value + +document.getElementById("add_on").value;

    document.getElementById("sub_total").value = isNaN(SubTotal) ? 0 : SubTotal;
}


document.getElementById("add_on").onchange = calculateSubTotal;
document.getElementById("add_on").onkeyup = calculateSubTotal;
document.getElementById("total_full").onchange = calculateSubTotal;
document.getElementById("total_full").onkeyup = calculateSubTotal;
document.getElementById("total_half").onchange = calculateSubTotal;
document.getElementById("total_half").onkeyup = calculateSubTotal;
calculateSubTotal;
document.getElementById("total_half").onchange = calculateSubTotal;
document.getElementById("total_half").onkeyup = calculateSubTotal;
```

​

http://jsfiddle.net/newbie123/ue62p/5/

Comment: Where are you putting the javascript code in your file?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté within script tags at the bottom of the HTML

Comment: It should work then. Check your JS console (IE/Chrome: F12; Firefox: Ctrl+Shift+K) and check if there are any errors in the console. (open console, refresh page, type some numbers in the fields)

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: there are no errors in the console?  I can calculate the sub total field if i add the event on another field which I input text into, but it only wont work on the fields which are automatically calculated?

Comment: I've read your question about 5 times but I'm still not sure what's the problem.. the `Sub Total` is not being updated when you type in others fields on your page? Sorry, I still don't get it.

Comment: I have found the solution :-)  thank you so much for your assistance. i am sorry if my question was confusing to understand

Comment: Oh no problem, I just figured it a couple mins ago that you wanted your function to fire when updating your fields through JS, and yes, your answer is right, you have to call it manually unless adding eventListeners. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

onChange only fires when a user updates the value. If you want that functionality, you're going to have to add calculateSubTotal to the events where total_full and total_half are updated.